# Inserting a substring value into an already existing entry

Tags: mysql

Currently I have a database with the following parameters and entry:

[image]

Now I want to fill the column status_from in this particular entry with the id 1 with a substring of the action column. Which is basically I want to fill my status_from column with a word that comes after from and before to of the action column. To achieve this I've tried using the following statement:

```
INSERT INTO crm_logs2(status_from) SELECT status_from WHERE id='1' VALUES (substring_index(substring_index(action, 'from', -1),'to', 1))
```

But doing this gave me the following error:

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'VALUES (substring_index(substring_index(action, 'from', -1), ...' at line 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the UPDATE statement

```
UPDATE crm_logs2 
SET status_from = (SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(action, "from", -1), "to", 1))
WHERE id = 1
```

Comment: There is no need for a select inside a select.

Comment: @SalmanA Its a select within an update statement. The OP was looking for a solution to update an existing row's **status_from** field depending on a substring from that same rows **action** field.

Comment: Yes but you're updating one column based on another column from same row in same table. E.g. `UPDATE ... SET status_from = SUBSTRING(action, 1, 2) WHERE ...` would be enough.

Comment: @SalmanA You are correct, my bad! Answer updated

Answer (score 0):

```
update crm_logs2
set action=(select SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(action, ' ', 6), ' ', -1) from 
crm_logs2 where id=1)where id=1
```

Try this and let us know if it works